# Get last numbers in string separated by an unknown delimiter

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to parse titles, and I can't quite figure out how to isolate the last numbers in the string, I think I got the delimiter figured out (with those nested if statements), but Im still failing my own test cases. Any advice?

Current output:

```
1801 (150@$5): 1801
0055 30 @ $5: 0055
leaver - 8 @ $10: 8
ATS-55) - 45/$2: 55
```

End goal:

```
1801 (150@$5): 150
0055 30 @ $5: 30
leaver - 8 @ $10: 8
ATS-55) - 45/$2: 45
```

My code

```
import re

def getSlots(title):
    x=title.split('@')
    if len(x)<2: #this means @ wasnt used as the delimeter
        x=title.split('/')
        if len(x)<2:
            x=title.split(' ')
            if len(x)<2:
                return "unsolvable";

    m = re.search('\d+', x[0])
    return m.group(0);

testlist=['1801 (150@$5)','0055 30 @ $5','leaver - 8 @ $10','ATS-55) - 45/$2']
for t in testlist:
    print(t+': '+getSlots(t))
```

Comment: Will the delimeter always just be, going backwards, the characters from the $ sign to the first number?

Comment: "...I can't quite figure out how to isolate the last numbers in the string" From your examples, you're not looking for the last numbers in the string - can you please clarify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a regular expression and the assumption that the required digit string is followed by one or more space, `@`, or `/` characters and a final `$`:

```
import re

testlist = ['1801 (150@$5)', '0055 30 @ $5', 'leaver - 8 @ $10', 'ATS-55) - 45/$2']

for s in testlist:
    match = re.search(r'(\d+)[ @/]+\$', s)
    if match:
        print('{}: {}'.format(s, match.groups()[0]))
```

**Output**

```
1801 (150@$5): 150
0055 30 @ $5: 30
leaver - 8 @ $10: 8
ATS-55) - 45/$2: 45
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the number you're looking for is always the set of consecutive, contiguous digits to the left of the dollar sign, something like the following seems to work:

```
lines = [
    '1801 (150@$5): 1801',
    '0055 30 @ $5: 0055',
    'leaver - 8 @ $10: 8',
    'ATS-55) - 45/$2: 55',
]

def extract(line):
    # Assumes there's only one $ symbol
    dsp = line.index('$')

    # Find last index
    last_index = dsp - 1
    while not line[last_index].isdigit():
        last_index -= 1

    # Find first index
    first_index = last_index
    while line[first_index-1].isdigit():
        first_index -= 1

    return line[first_index:last_index+1]

for line in lines:
    print(extract(line))
```

**Result:**

```
'1801 (150@$5): 1801'       => 150
'0055 30 @ $5: 0055'        =>  30
'leaver - 8 @ $10: 8'       =>   8
'ATS-55) - 45/$2: 55',150   =>  45
```

Note the return value of `extract()` is a string, you may wish to convert this to an int.

Answer (score 0):

You may extract a digit sequence (with `\d+`) that is followed with 0+ whitespace chars followed with `@` or `/` (using the `(?=\s*[@/])` lookahead). Note you may update the `[@/]` character class to include any more delimiting chars, or add `|...` if the delimiting string is a sequence of chars):

```
import re
lst = ['1801 (150@$5)', '0055 30 @ $5', 'leaver - 8 @ $10', 'ATS-55) - 45/$2', 'Not solvable']
for s in lst:
    m = re.search(r'\d+(?=\s*[@/])', s)
    if m:
        print("{}: {}".format(s, m.group()))
    else:
        print("{}: unsolvable".format(s))
```

See the Python demo, output:

```
1801 (150@$5): 150
0055 30 @ $5: 30
leaver - 8 @ $10: 8
ATS-55) - 45/$2: 45
Not solvable: unsolvable
```

**Pattern details**

- `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `(?=\s*[@/])` - a positive lookahead that asserts the presence (requires the presence) of

  - `\s*` - 0 or more whitespace chars
  - `[@/]` - a `@` or `/` chars.